# Javamail Configuration clarification

Tags: jakarta-mail

Through my application using Javamail API  if I want to send email between any two external email addresses say **gmail->yahoo** or **yahoo->gmail** or any other email account without using authentication mechanism how should I configure **mail.smtp.host** property?

What is the correct way of configuring javamail properties for sending emails between any two external email addresses ?

Sample code to send mail is given below:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties(),null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com"));  
InternetAddress[] toAddress = {new InternetAddress("test@yahoo.com")};  
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);  
message.setSubject("test mail");  message.setText("test body");  
Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most public mail servers require authentication.  If you want to do it without authentication, you'll need to run your own mail server.

Answer (score 0):

This is for gmail, try it. You need `mail.jar`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String username = "yourId@gmail.com";
    final String password = "your-pwd";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("yourId@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("some-mail@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("A Mail Subject");
        message.setText("Hey I'm sending mail using java api");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

**Edit :**

[Link to download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html) Java mail Api along with `mail.jar`